# How can I CREATE multiple records at once in Rails POST CREATE controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, post

I currently have a few models like User, UserMovieList, and UserMovieListItem.

The User can create a list of their favorite comedy movies or favorite horror movies for example. After creating a new list, let's say 'My Favorite Horror Films' they can then add entries to the list. They may add 'Friday the 13th' and 'The Ring', and then save.

Right now I'm adding these 2 movies in 2 separate POSTS to the web server so they are added to UserMovieListItem.

I want to be able to add them in 1 POST.

```
{
  "user_movie_list_item":
  {
    "title": "Friday the 13th"
  }     
}
```

I would like to be able to send in

```
{
  "user_movie_list_item":
  {
    "title": "Friday the 13th"
  },
  {
    "title": "The Ring"
  }  
}
```

1) Is this the right format for the JSON to send multiple entries?

2) How do I do this in my controller?

Right now I have...

```
def create
    if authenticate_user
        user_movie_list = @current_user.user_movie_lists.find_by_id(params[:user_movie_list_id])
        user_movie_list_item = user_movie_list.user_movie_list_items.new(user_movie_list_item_params)
        if (user_movie_list_item.save!)
            respond_with :api, :v1, @current_user, user_movie_list, user_movie_list_item, location: nil, serializer: Api::V1::UserMovieListItemSerializer
        else
            render json: { error: "Could not create new User Movie List Item."}, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end         
    else
        render json: { error: "User is not signed in." }, status: :unauthorized
    end
end
```

How can I make it so I can add multiple records at once?

Comment: I recommend replacing the "if authenticate_user" with a "before_action :authenticate_user!".

Answer (score 0):

In your model, you can override assignments like this:

```
def user_movie_list=(list)
  list.each do | l |
     ml = user_movie_list_items.new
     ml.title = l.title

     ... # configure your list

     ml.save!
  end
end
```

JSON list are:

```
{ "my_list": [{"title": "blah"}, {"title": "foo"}, ... ] }
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I define the params to be a JSON array? def user_movie_list_item_params params.require(:user_movie_list_item).permit(:user_movie_list_id, :title, ) end Or Are you saying I can go def user_movie_list_item_params=(list) and iterate that?